# Limit of $\frac{xy}{3x^2+2y}$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have a problem with the following limit:

$$ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy}{3x^2+2y}$$

How can I calculate it (if it exists)?

Answer (score 7):

The limit does not exist because if we consider $$\lim_{x \to 0} f\bigl(x,(x-\tfrac{3}{2})x^2\bigr) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x-3}{4} = -\frac{3}{4},$$ but obviously $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,x) = 0.$$

---

I finally was able to make a nice plot of this function.  It was tricky because of the behavior at the origin.  The red line shows the path given in the above limit, but it should be obvious from the surface itself that the limit at the origin is undefined.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the statement "If the iterated limits do not exist or differ, then the double limit does not exist"?

Comment: There, I have used a different argument, which should easily suffice.

Comment: @heropup is it witchcraft you used to get the first expression ? +1

Comment: @G.T.R Thanks for the upvote.  The particular choice of $y = (x-\frac{3}{2})x^2$ was suggested by the form of the denominator of $f$, which is undefined if $y = -\frac{3}{2}x^2$.  But since we can't just directly take a limit along this path, I originally thought to introduce a parameter $k \to -3/2$ with $y = kx^2$.  But then it occurred to me that if I could tie the limiting behavior of $k$ to that of $x$, maybe I could get a path that doesn't tend to $0$, which led to the choice shown above.

Comment: @heropup Very satisfying, thanks.